# Role based security for tabs/pages in PowerBI (not row level secuity)

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server, role-based-access-control

Is there a way to provide role based security for different tabs/pages on PowerBi cloud desktop version. As in, if I have a PowerBI report with 27 different tabs used by 4 departments, can we restrict access to each department based on tabs that is relevant to them. like maybe department 4 is only interested in tabs/pages 2,3,6,8 while department 2 is only interested in tabs/pages 2,7,8,11,21,23 so only those tabs from reports should be visible to them.

The challenge I faced in row level security- The whole framework/skeleton of report along with non-relevant calculations is visible to each user.

Answer (score 1):

No, but this idea is submitted to Microsoft with a status "under review" and you may vote for it:

https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/16059178-page-tab-level-security

Comment: Thanks for helping me out